# what is useraccount class used for?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am new to aspnetboilerplate.When I read source code,I found UserAccount class which also create a table in database.I found it create after abpuser create,but I could not find any other usage.Does somebody know what is useraccount used for?

Answer (score 0):

UserAccount register all tenant users on a single place so you can access all users on this table (model) without removing any filter. Very good if you have tenant per database approach. One good use is you want unique user email not matter tenant.

Comment: can you please share the example of tenant per database or git repo